# Extend JSDoc with external documentation

Tags: javascript, documentation, documentation-generation, jsdoc

is there a possibility to extend JSDoc with an external docu file?
My problem is, by writing all the docu in the .js file, the size grows heavy and thats bad for the readability of the code. I also want to add some examples in the docu. In JSDoc i only find to add links, but thats not what i want.

An example:

```
/** 
*Bla bla bla
* 
* para1= ...
* 
* {@LINK_TO_EXTERNAL_DOC@}
* {@LINK_TO_EXTERNAL_EXAMPLES@}
*/
```

By generating the docu, the content of the external files should be "inlined" and printed in the docu without a link.

Thanks

Comment: Rather late at this point, but I think this question's answers are relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51840516/javascript-move-jsdocs-outside-of-code/52058542?r=SearchResults&s=34|17.4474#52058542