# Javascript: Move JSDoc's outside of code

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I ask this mostly from a Angular perspective (but any advice would help). I have JSDoc's on my functions but it makes the code look very messy. I would just like to know if there is a way to move the JSDoc's to some type of external file.

An example of my JSDoc's:

```
/**
* Does a GET call on the service MyGetCall
* @param {string} pUserID - 1st Parameter: User Login ID
* @param {string} pPassword - 2nd Parameter: User Password
* @returns The Call's Http Observable (subscribe to this function).
* @example this.flowservice.MyGetCall('Johnny', 'MySuperSecretPassword')
*              .subscribe(response => {
*                  console.log(response)
*              });
*/
MyGetCall(pUserID: string, pPassword: string): Observable<any> {
    const temp = this.httpclient.get<JSON>(`http://XXX/MyGetCall?userid=${pUserID}&password=${pPassword}`, {headers: this.headers});
    return temp;
}
```

So in this example I would like to remove all the JSDoc's and put it in some kind of external file (jsdocs.xxx). This file would then look something like this:

```
MyGetCall:
    /**
    * Does a GET call on the service MyGetCall
    * @param {string} pUserID - 1st Parameter: User Login ID
    * @param {string} pPassword - 2nd Parameter: User Password
    * @returns The Call's Http Observable (subscribe to this function).
    * @example this.flowservice.MyGetCall('Johnny', 'MySuperSecretPassword')
    *              .subscribe(response => {
    *                  console.log(response)
    *              });
    */

MyOtherFunction:
    ...

MyOtherOtherFunction:
    ...
```

Then I can import this file (jsdocs.xxx) somewhere for it to work with my app. For anyone that has used JSDoc's I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Perhaps you can use this plugin to move at least the examples to outside of source file: https://github.com/jugglinmike/jsdoc-external-example

Comment: Ah this is cool. Thank you! But of course this does not really solve the problem yet

Comment: You can make jsdoc comments anywhere.  If they aren't immediately adjacent to a function or method, the parser can't know that it is a function by itself, so you can add the `@function <function name>` tag in the stand-alone comment.

Comment: @garlon4 Would you mind adding an answer please, with an example. I can't seem to get this idea working.

Comment: Check out this answer too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43183450/jsdoc-typedef-in-a-separate-file

Answer (score 4):

If, inline, I would document a class method like so:

```
/**
 * @class 
 * @alias fileReader
 */
function fileReader() {
  /**
   * Tells the caller if it can handle the given file by returning a boolean.
   *
   * @param {File} file A `File` object.
   * @returns {boolean} `true` if this reader can read a file.
   */  
  this.canRead = function (file) {
    ...
  };
}
```

Instead, I could document my method somewhere else:

```
/**
 * @class 
 * @alias fileReader
 */
function fileReader() {
  this.canRead = function (file) {
    ...
  };
}
```

And the documentation could be in a different file, like so:

```
/**
 * Tells the caller if it can handle the given file by returning a boolean.
 *
 * @function canRead
 * @memberof fileReader
 * @instance
 * @param {File} file A `File` object.
 * @returns {boolean} `true` if this reader can read a file.
 */
```

The `@function` parameter defines the name of the function if the jsdoc isn't immediately followed by an actual function.  The `@memberof` tells it the parent class or namespace.  The `@instance` says that it is a method that requires an instantiated class rather.

For your example, I'm guessing that the documentation would be

```
/**
* Does a GET call on the service MyGetCall
* @function MyGetCall
* @memberof flowservice
* @instance
* @param {string} pUserID - 1st Parameter: User Login ID
* @param {string} pPassword - 2nd Parameter: User Password
* @returns The Call's Http Observable (subscribe to this function).
* @example this.flowservice.MyGetCall('Johnny', 'MySuperSecretPassword')
*              .subscribe(response => {
*                  console.log(response)
*              });
*/
```

Comment: how do you include the external file?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is mostly catered to VS Code if you're hoping to get Intellisense to pick up your types.

I've had success with simply creating my types in a `typedefs.js` file and referencing the type by using the ts/vscode `import(path/to/file).Foo` tag.

JSDoc does not support this syntax out of the box, so I suggest also using [jsdoc-tsimport-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdoc-tsimport-plugin) in order to parse your docs.

Eg: typedef.js:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Foo
 * @property {string} id
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} Bar
 * @property {string[]} things
 */

// having to export an empty object here is annoying, 
// but required for vscode to pass on your types. 
export {};
```

coolFunction.js

```js
/**
 * This function is super dope
 * @param {import('../typedef').Foo} foo - a foo
 * @return {import('../typedef').Bar} bar - an array of bars
 */

 export function (foo) {
    // do cool things
    return bar;
 }
```